# How to use <Say> multiple times in one call?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

How can I use `<Say>` multiple times in one call? I have come up with an example for my question:

```
exports.handler = async function (context, event, callback) {
  try {
    const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    const client = context.getTwilioClient();
    console.log("The call is " + JSON.stringify(event.CallSid));
    var i = 0;
    const sentences = ['Ahoy there', 'How are you today?', 'Nice to meet you', 'Hope you have a great day', 'Goodbye'];

    const intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
      if (i < sentences.length) {
        const resp = await client.calls(event.CallSid).update({
          twiml: `<Response><Say>${sentences[i]}</Say></Response>`
        });
        i += 1;
      } else {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        return callback(null, twiml);
      }
    }, 3000); // update every 3 seconds
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

Here, there are a set of four sentences that I would like to say separately every three seconds. I am following the update documentation [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?code-sample=code-update-a-call-in-progress-with-twiml&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json#update-a-call-resource).

But, this doesn't seem to work. It just leads to a Twilio timeout. Is there a way to do this without having to recursively return a callback and redirect each time?

Answer (score 2):

Try to construct a single TwiML instruction that includes all the `<Say>` and use `<Pause>` to introduce the delays between the sentences.

```
exports.handler = async function (context, event, callback) {
 try {
    const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    const client = context.getTwilioClient();
    console.log("The call is " + JSON.stringify(event.CallSid));
    const sentences = ['Ahoy there', 'How are you today?', 'Nice to meet you', 'Hope you have a great day', 'Goodbye'];

    // Create a single TwiML instruction with all the <Say> tags and <Pause> tags
    let twimlInstruction = '<Response>';
    for (let sentence of sentences) {
      twimlInstruction += `<Say>${sentence}</Say><Pause length="3"/>`;
    }
    twimlInstruction += '</Response>';

    const resp = await client.calls(event.CallSid).update({
      twiml: twimlInstruction
    });
    return callback(null, twiml);
 } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
 }
};
```